# Как подсчитать количество одинаковых значений в списке?

Tags: kotlin, list

Не могу разобраться с массивом данных. При исполнении кода имею массив как минимум с 3мя одинаковыми значениями. Как их объединить в одно и подсчитать их количество?

```
fun value(){
    if (_quantity.value == list.size) {
        _flavor.value = list.toString()
    } else {
        val addNumberCup = (_quantity.value?.minus(list.size))
        Log.d("MyTag", "$addNumberCup")
        repeat(addNumberCup.hashCode()) {
            list.add(_flavor.value.toString())
        }
        Log.d("MyTag", "$list")
        _flavor.value = list.toString()
    }
}
```

---

```
val listParametr = mutableListOf("Кофе","Соленая карамель")
repeat(3) {
list.add(listParametr.joinToString())
}
```

На выходе получаю такие данные

```
list = mutableListOf("Кофе","Соленая карамель","Кофе","Соленая карамель","Кофе","Соленая карамель")
```

Comment: приведите пример исходного массива и того, что ожидаетс на выходе. Сейчас невозможно понять, что вам требуется получить.

Comment: val list = "Красный бархат, Соленая карамель, Соленая карамель, Соленая карамель, Соленая карамель, Соленая карамель" Ожидаю на выходе: Красный бархат = 1, Соленая карамель=5

Comment: list  тут строка, а не массив.

Answer (score 2):

Если действительно массив, а не строка, как в комментарии, то можно так:

```
val data = list.groupingBy { it }.eachCount()
```

В `data` будет такой словарь:

```
{Красный бархат=1, Соленая карамель=5}
```

Comment: Работает, но почему то не полностью. Сталкиваюсь вот с таким выводом. {Соленая карамель, Красный бархат=3}

Comment: какие данные на входе?

Comment: val data = list.groupingBy { it }.eachCount()
            Log.d("MyTag", "$data")
            
            Данные выхода:
            {Соленая карамель, Красный бархат=3}

Comment: да на входе что, а не на выходе. Что в list?

Comment: [Кофе, Соленая карамель, Кофе, Соленая карамель, Кофе, Соленая карамель]

Comment: это вряд ли. Потому что а) это не массив, б) откуда у вас тогда в выводе Красный бархат и куда делся Кофе?

Comment: Данные в переменной меняются в зависимости от того, что пользователь выбрал. Прошу прощения что Вас ввёл в заблуждение в последнем комментарии. данные на входе val list = mutableListOf<String> , переменная заполняется данными которые мы выбираем. Обычно это 2, 3 строки. Дальше происходит логика копирования и обновления переменной, до такого вида: [Кофе, Соленая карамель, Кофе, Соленая карамель, Кофе, Соленая карамель]. получается что переменная выглядит так: val list = mutableListOf("Кофе" , "Соленая карамель" , "Кофе", "Соленая карамель", "Кофе", "Соленая карамель" )

Comment: т.е. на такой переменной (с кофе и без бархата) у вас выводит  {Соленая карамель, Красный бархат=3}?

Comment: От переменной не зависит, в любом случае на выходе получается {Соленая карамель, Красный бархат=3}, либо {Кофе, Соленая карамель=3}. Правильно выходит лишь второй элемент итогового списка.

Comment: значит у вас есть еще что-то, что изменяет входные данные. Или все таки входные данные не такие. Что выводит Log.d("MyTag", "$list") ?

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста, ниже ответом на свой вопрос прокомментировал.

Comment: Добавлю сюда. В результате хитрых манипуляций в списке получалось три элемента "Кофе, Соленая карамель", а не три "Кофе" и три "Соленая карамель". Т.е. было ``("Кофе, Соленая карамель", "Кофе, Соленая карамель", "Кофе, Соленая карамель")``, а не ``("Кофе" , "Соленая карамель" , "Кофе", "Соленая карамель", "Кофе", "Соленая карамель" )``. Поэтому и результат был ``{Кофе, Соленая карамель=3}``.